# I want to manipulate list of dictionaries to list of lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to manipulate list of dictionaries to list of lists in python.

The data looks like below

```
before_data = [
    {
        "itemid": "23743",
        "lastclock": "1574390042",
        "lastvalue": "2798",
        "name": "cl Loaded Class Count"
    },
    {
        "itemid": "23744",
        "lastclock": "1574390042",
        "lastvalue": "2846",
        "name": "cl Total Loaded Class Count"
    },
    {
        "itemid": "23745",
        "lastclock": "1574390042",
        "lastvalue": "48",
        "name": "cl Unloaded Class Count"
    }]
```

I require below

```
require_data = [['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue'],['cl Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2798'],['cl Total Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2846'],['cl Unloaded Class Count', '1574390042', '48']]
```

I tried list comprehension like below but did not worked

```
before_data =[before_data['name'] for i in before_data]
```

Comment: Please expand on *"did not worked"* - give a [mcve]. I'd expect that to give `['cl Loaded Class Count', 'cl Total Loaded Class Count', ...]` without any errors - if you want a list of lists, why is the value in the list comprehension just one string?

Comment: Also, how do values like `lastclock` become `Last clock` in your expected output?

Comment: Did you try writing a `for` loop?

Comment: It’s worth avoiding list comprehensions until you are more confident. Comprehensions are great because they are very succinct (few lines of code) but the downside is that that they are impossible to debug. Start by writing for loops and you’ll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want this:

```
before_data =[[i["name"], i["lastclock"], i["lastvalue"]]  for i in before_data]
```

**OUT:**

```
[['cl Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2798'], ['cl Total Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2846'], ['cl Unloaded Class Count', '1574390042', '48']]
```

If you really want to insert keys as well you can do it like:

```
before_data = [['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue']] + before_data
```

**OUT:**

```
[['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue'], ['cl Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2798'], ['cl Total Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2846'], ['cl Unloaded Class Count', '1574390042', '48']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with a naive approach, intentionally didn't use list comprehension for your better understanding.

```py
l=[]

l.append(list(before_data[0].keys()))
for i in before_data:
    l.append(list(i.values()))

print(l)
```

All I did was to add the headers/keys first in the list, then iteratively added created a list of values and then added it to the main list.

**Important**
The method I have used is applicable for static dictionary, I you rather go for dynamic, i.e., through input or some streaming pipeline, this method will give unpredictable behavior as because `dict` is an unordered data structure, so rather going will indexing via key is a better option.
Example
`before_data[0]["itemid"]` or `before_data[0]["lastvalue"]`

Comment: Mostly this will not result in the required order of the data, as `dict` is unordered data type.

Comment: @Geeocode I agree with what you are saying. Apparently, here the dictionary is static, so using keys() and values() function will return the same values in the desired order. Moreover, I automated the script and ran it for 100 times, each time it generated identical results.

Comment: There will be cases where `dict` will be in the desired order, but we can not count on this, as dict is unordered as I wrote above and you know as well. So if we want to be sure to get the particular order, then we can not use these function.

Comment: @Geeocode As I mentioned on the Answer, this is an absolute naive approach to the problem. I am aware of the issue you stated. I am not quite sure, but for static dictionary it shouldn't create any problem. I totally agree with the fact that ```dict``` is unordered, but I guess here the solution suits the problem. You can try it yourself. Just create a bash script to keep the python file running. You will see that every time the results are absolutely identical.

Comment: Debdut, as OP's question was not exact, so complete your answer with the note regarding this particular possible issue and it will be fine for me too. I have had a lot of issues from this behaviour of `dict` so let we give the chance the future reader to avoid these problems.

Comment: Hey, you are right. That's my bad. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Geeocode Not clear what version of Python OP is using, but in Python 3.7+, dictionaries are guaranteed to return keys in order of insertion, i.e. they are _not_ unordered.

Comment: @barny Yes, but only from 3.7+ but it is even not true in 2.x. So without nowing the specific Python version we can't say for sure.

Comment: My point is that you _were_ “saying for sure” that “dict is unordered type”, which is not correct for CPython.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pandas way to convert it:

```
import pandas as pd
required_data = pd.DataFrame(before_data, columns=['name', 'lastclock', 'lastvalue']).to_numpy().tolist() 
require_data.insert(0, ['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue'])
require_data 
#[['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue'],
#['cl Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2798'],
#['cl Total Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2846'],
#['cl Unloaded Class Count', '1574390042', '48']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access items in the dictionary then add the headers after

```
before_data2 = [[i['name'], i['lastclock'], i['lastvalue']] for i in before_data]
before_data2 = [['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue']] + before_data2
before_data2
```

Result:

```
[['Item Name', 'Last clock', 'lastvalue'],
 ['cl Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2798'],
 ['cl Total Loaded Class Count', '1574390042', '2846'],
 ['cl Unloaded Class Count', '1574390042', '48']]
```